# How send element in email with background-color Made of variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to send an email that contains an element from my component.

The element is sent from the Angular to c# and in c# it is sent to the customer.

The element is:

[image]

**In print it is fine but when sending an email i get the following:**
[image]

The sending is made from the following code:

**The content:**

**html**

```
<div id="print-section" >
<div>
    <h1 >your makeup:</h1>
    <label>id: </label><span>{{product.id}}</span><br/>
    <label>codeInCompany: </label><span>{{product.codeInCompany}}</span><br/>
    <span id="color"></span><br>
    <span style="display:none" id='r'>{{product.r}}</span>
    <span style="display:none" id='g'>{{product.g}}</span>
    <span  style="display:none" id='b'>{{product.b}}</span>
    <label>price: </label><span>{{product.price}}</span><br/>
    <label>description: </label><span>{{product.description}}</span><br/>
    <label >company name: </label><span>{{product.company.name}}</span><br/>
    <h2 >thank you and have a good day!</h2>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
let printContents;
//The element to be printed:
printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;

let message:string=`
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Print tab</title>
        <style> </style>
        <script>
         function color(){
           if(document.getElementById("r")!=null && document.getElementById("g")!=null && document.getElementById("b")!=null)
           {
             var r=document.getElementById("r").innerHTML;
             var g=document.getElementById("g").innerHTML;
             var b =document.getElementById("b").innerHTML;
             let style1="background-color: rgb"+"("+r+" "+ g+" "+b+")";
             var d=document.querySelector("[id*=color]");
             d.setAttribute("style",style1);
           }
         }
         window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
           color();
         });
      </script>
       
     </head>
     <body onload="color()">${printContents}</body>
  </html>`;
```

**Sending to server:**

```
 this.customerService.sendMail(this.address,message).subscribe(
    data=>{
       this.alert="Email sent successfully";
    },
    fail=> {
       this.alert="Sorry, There is a problem with send email";
    });
```

Can you help me?

Comment: can you please do console.log(style1)? what will you get?

Comment: @Riddhi i edit the ts in my question. when i put console.log() in a development environment i see that i  I did not register the body correctly for the event. i fix it. but now I still can't see the color.
How can I see a console.log() when the email is received in Gmail?

Comment: do you have any `index` file or anything in which you can print your `message` variable?

Comment: @Riddhi The message is sent by email. The customer opens the email in Gmail. How can I see a console in Gmail?

Comment: have you tried static color like #000 or else I found `RGB values didn’t fare much better, resulting in a few lovely shades of green (despite specifying values for white and gray):` from https://www.litmus.com/blog/background-colors-html-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way the style is placed in the element:
instead of:  `d.setAttribute` in `ts`, i use with `[style]` in `html`.

The whole code:

**html**

```
<div id="print-section" >
<div>
    <h1>your makeup</h1>
    <label>id: </label><span>{{product.id}}</span><br/>
    <label>codeInCompany: </label><span>{{product.codeInCompany}}</span><br/>
    <span name="color" id="color" [style]="myStyle">color</span><br>
    <span style="display:none" id='r'>{{product.r}}</span>
    <span style="display:none" id='g'>{{product.g}}</span>
    <span  style="display:none" id='b'>{{product.b}}</span>
    <label>price: </label><span>{{product.price}}</span><br/>
    <label>description: </label><span>{{product.description}}</span><br/>
    <label>company name: </label><span>{{product.company.name}}</span><br/>
    <h2>thank you and have a good day</h2>
</div>
```

**ts**

//color element by variables

```
 myStyle="";

 ngOnInit() {
    this.colorlabel();
  }
  colorlabel(){
        var r=this.product.r;
        var g=this.product.g;
        var b=this.product.b;
        let style1="background-color: rgb"+"("+r+" "+ g+" "+b+");padding-top:20px";
        style1+=';width: 100px;height: 100px;border-radius: 50%;font-size:20px;font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times,Times New Roman, serif;font-weight: 600;display: inline-block;text-align:center;';
        this.myStyle=style1;
  }
```

//send to server

```
let printContents;
printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
let message:string=`
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Email tab</title>
  </head>
  <body>${printContents}</body>
</html>`;
this.customerService.sendMail(this.address,message).subscribe(
  data=>{
    this.alert="Email sent successfully";
  },
  fail=> {
    this.alert="Sorry, There is a problem with send email";
  }
);
```